# Redirect domain to app

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to be able to use custom domains for my application. For example a customer purchases a domain lets call it example.com and I want that he can use the domain on myapp.com

- How can I achieve that all traffic coming from example.com lands in myapp.com?
- Can I do this with htaccess (mod_rewrite) or do I need to have a CNAME record?

Can someone please explain what I need to do step by step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Have your customer point either an `A` or `CNAME` DNS record to your host.
2. Make sure Apache listens to requests for the domain name. This can be done with multiple vhosts for the different domains or one that listens to everything.

Everything else is up to your app logic, including the question if you need something like mod_rewrite at all. In many cases, you won't need to.

Comment: App logic is fine, can you add details about the other steps?

Comment: +1. If you want each domain to have a custom version of your app, you will need .htaccess to send the domain data to your app as a parameter.

Comment: If you have a dedicated IP and only 1 site, you may be able to avoid configuring virtualhosts in apache. If you are on a shared account without a dedicated IP, you will need to configure each domain as SvW said.

Comment: I can't go into more details unless I want to write a book as I don't know what you need and on what kind of system you are etc.etc. Please read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ to learn how to configure Apache to your liking.

Comment: Well the basic scenario is this, I have a app that displays a page for each customer, but the customer should be able to map the whole thing to his own domain. Like myapp.com/user/abc but this content should be accessible from abc.com. So can I simply add a CNAME and forward that to myapp.com and let myapp.com detect from which domain the call is coming from?